# must-non constant alias argument with its default argument constant

Tags: c++, c++17, constants, bind

How do we code a must-non constant alias argument with its default argument must be constant as it's not being able to reference ?
and must be without overload function as its 91 lines long

```
Bar {
  int on;
  Bar(){};
  Bar(bool o): off{o}{}
  bool off; 
}

int fooBar(int board, Bar& bar = static_cast<Bar>(1)) {

//...
}
```

gcc gave

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Bar&' to an
>   rvalue of type 'Bar'

How to solve - with clear explanation - such this kind ?

Comment: Why no overload? The overload only needs to be 4 lines long: see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get this error is, as you've discovered, that a non-`const` reference must bind to an lvalue: that is, it must bind to an object with a name. A temporary will not bind to a non-`const` reference: only to `const Bar&` or `Bar&&`, neither of which you want.

That leaves us a couple of options.

My personal favourite would be to not use default arguments at all, but instead provide an overload:

```cpp
int fooBar(int board, Bar& bar) {
  // ...
}

int fooBar(int board) {
  // to save code duplication you can call in fooBar
  Bar b{1};
  return fooBar(board, b);
}
```

This is the easiest and most consistent option, in my opinion.

Other possibilities include:

- making a global whose sole purpose is to be a default argument (yuck, and interferes with multithreading):

  ```cpp
  inline Bar default_bar;
  int fooBar(int board, Bar& bar = default_bar) {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- using a pointer instead, with the caveat that you must check if they've provided an argument or not:

  ```cpp
  int fooBar(int board, Bar* bar = nullptr) {
    // ..., but make sure to test bar!
  }
  ```
- or otherwise using a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Bar>>` or some-such type.

Answer (score 0):

You can define such helper function:

```cpp
template <typename Ty> Ty &make_ref(const Ty &cref)
{
    return const_cast<Ty&>(cref);
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```cpp
int fooBar(int board, Bar& bar = make_ref(Bar(1))) {
//...
}
```